# Polymorphic XML Binding with JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Here is what I am trying to do:

XML is this:

```
<Doctype1>
    <Outter>
        <Inner>
          <ProblemType>
              <foo>...</foo>
              <baz>...</baz>
          </ProblemType>
        </Inner>
    </Outter>
</Doctype1>
```

<--  However, I have: -->

```
<Doctype2>
    <Outter>
        <Inner>
          <ProblemType>
              <blah>...</blah>
              <whatever>...</whatever>
          </ProblemType>
        </Inner>
    </Outter>
</Doctype1>
```

and 
Share most of the same fields, but in the case of Doctype1 I need ProblemType1 and in Doctype2 I need ProblemType2.

I want to be able to reuse the classes I bind to for  and  as they are a common tag across all doc types.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Doc1{

    @XmlElement(name = "Outter")
    public List<Outter> outtards;

}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Outter {

    @XmlElement(name = "Inner")
    public List<Innard> innards;
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Innard{

    // need to change this if it's Doc1 or Doc2. 
    //The subtype of problem type needs to change based on DocX
    // the element type name won't change
    @XmlElement(name = "Inner")
    public ProblemType subtype; 
}
```

It seems like Maybe a factory is in order?

```
@XmlType(factoryClass= , factoryMethod=)
```

Comment: Could you please also post `Doc2`? And better make it an answer - unaccept mine and accept yours. (Think of the future readers.)

Comment: Done. Not sure it helps future readers but ok. I do want to give you props for giving me some validation. I am going to continue to investigate possibilities.

Comment: It *may* help and is the right thing to do. Well done. :)

Comment: I reposted a variant of this question that really gets more precisely to the problem. The subclass thing 'works' but it's ugly an requires me to override methods for silliness sake

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28185692/how-to-choose-a-specific-subtype-to-bind-to-based-on-qualifiers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
    public class Doc1 {

        @XmlElement(type = Outter1.class, name = "Outter")
        private List<Outter> outters;

        public static class Outter1 extends Outter {

            @Override
            @XmlElement(type = Inner1.class, name = "Inner")
            public List<Inner> getInner() {
                return super.getInner();
            }

            @Override
            public void setInner(List<Inner> innards) {
                super.setInner(innards);
            }

            public static class Inner1 extends Inner<ProblemType1> {

                @Override
                @XmlElement(type = ProblemType1.class, name = "ProblemType")
                public List<ProblemType> getProblemTypes() {
                    return super.getProblemTypes();
                }

                @Override
                public void setProblemTypes(List<ProblemType> problemTypes) {
                    super.setProblemTypes(problemTypes);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

other class

```
public class Doc2 {

    @XmlElement(type = Outter2.class, name= "Outter")
    private List<Outter> outters;

    public static class Outter2 extends Outter {

        @Override
        @XmlElement(type = Outter2.class, name = "Inner")
        public List<Inner> getInner() {
            return super.getInner();
        }

        @Override
        public void setInner(List<Inner> innards) {
            super.setInner(groups);
        }

        public static class Inner1 extends Inner<ProblemType2> {
            @Override
            @XmlElement(type = ProblemType2.class, name = "ProblemType")
            public List<ProblemType> getProblemTypes() {
                return super.getProblemTypes();
            }

            @Override
            public void setProblemTypes(List<ProblemType> transactions) {
                super.setProblemTypes(transactions);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have spent some time trying to reduce it but it doesn't seem to respond to XmlAccesorType.FIELD. If I use the same property name as the super or not it doesn't matter.

Comment: Looks good. Well done. Also try to experiment with `@XmlElementWrapper`, maybe you could save one level (i.e. `Outter`).

Comment: Post a follow up? Would love to save some lines.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, how would you implement such a structure in Java? There's some distance between `DoctypeX` and `ProblemTypeX`, so you can't polyform directly.

Probably with a structure like (very pseudo-code):

```
class AbstractDoctype {
  AbstractOuter getOuter();
}
class AbstractOuter {
  AbstractInner getInner();
}
class AbstractInner {
  AbstractProblemType getProblemType();
}
class AbstractProblemType {
}

class Doctype1 extends AbstractDoctype  {
  Outer1 getOuter();
}
class Outer1 extends AbstractOuter {
  Inner1 getInner();
}
class Inner1 extends AbstractInner {
  ProblemType1 getProblemType();
}
class ProblemType1 extends AbstractProblemType {
}

class Doctype2 extends AbstractDoctype  {
  Outer2 getOuter();
}
class Outer2 extends AbstractOuter {
  Inner2 getInner();
}
class Inner2 extends AbstractInner {
  ProblemType2 getProblemType();
}
class ProblemType2 extends AbstractProblemType {
}
```

This kind of structure will be then suitable for your XML. You can probably avoid `Outer1`/`Outer2` using an `@XmlElementWrapper`, but you'll still need `Inner1`/`Inner2`.

Comment: I updated the problem description. I realized last night it wasn't very clear and so I updated it. just now. Your idea might still have some merit. It's only the "ProblemType" that needs variation but I can't see a way to do that without doing everything you say.

Comment: @ChristianBongiorno I have checked your edit - I think it makes no difference for my answer. My point still stands. You'll need to polyform intermediate classes. I see no other way around. And try to think of how would you do it in Java.

Comment: You're probably right. I couldn't think of any other way myself but thought I would throw it out there and see if someone wiser than me could answer

Comment: @ChristianBongiorno Blaise Doughan may know better.

Comment: He most certainly might. Mmm, but does he just take random email questions?

Comment: I went and checked out his blog and got my final inspriation from him. Thanks for the help. I will continue to try to simplify this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a follow-up to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26989188/303810) in an attempt to save few lines with the [`@XmlElementWrapper`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElementWrapper.html). Since the `Outter` class seems to have no meaning on its own and it serves only as a container for the `Inner` class, it may be avoided:

Please try the following:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Doc1 {

        @XmlElementWrapper(name = "Outter")
        @XmlElement(type = Inner1.class, name = "Inner")
        public List<Inner> getInner() {
            return super.getInner();
        }

        @Override
        public void setInner(List<Inner> innards) {
            super.setInner(innards);
        }

        public static class Inner1 extends Inner<ProblemType1> {

            @Override
            @XmlElement(type = ProblemType1.class, name = "ProblemType")
            public List<ProblemType> getProblemTypes() {
                return super.getProblemTypes();
            }

            @Override
            public void setProblemTypes(List<ProblemType> problemTypes) {
                super.setProblemTypes(problemTypes);
            }
        }
}
```

However mind that this now a single list, not a list-of-lists. So this must be still possible with this construct:

```
<Doctype1>
    <Outter>
        <Inner>
          <ProblemType .../>
        </Inner>
        <Inner>
          <ProblemType .../>
        </Inner>
    </Outter>
</Doctype1>
```

But this is not:

```
<Doctype1>
    <Outter>
        <Inner>
          <ProblemType .../>
        </Inner>
    </Outter>
    <Outter>
        <Inner>
          <ProblemType .../>
        </Inner>
    </Outter>
</Doctype1>
```

Comment: Oh, Outter DOES have meaning. It contains like, 15 values I omitted for brevity sake :) Does it matter? Let me give this a go

Comment: @ChristianBongiorno OK, then you can't omit it, sorry. :)