# How to choose a specific subtype to bind to based on qualifiers

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Here is the XML I have (ish)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<edi837>
   <ISA >
      <ISA01>00</ISA01>
      <ISA02>          </ISA02>
      <GS>
         <GS01>HC</GS01>
         <GS07>X</GS07>
         <GS08>005010X223A2</GS08>
         <ST>
            <ST01>837</ST01>
            <ST02>0001</ST02>
            <ST03>005010X223A2</ST03>
            <BHT>
               <BHT01>19</BHT01>
               <BHT02>0</BHT02>
               <BHT03>524</BHT03>
               <BHT04>20111207</BHT04>
               <BHT05>1323</BHT05>
               <BHT06>CH</BHT06>
            </BHT>
            <Loop1000/>
            <Loop1000/>
            <Loop2000/>
            <Loop2000/>
         </ST>
      </GS>
   </ISA>
</edi837>
```

<--  However, I have: -->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<edi835>
   <ISA>
      <ISA01>00</ISA01>
      <ISA02>Authorizat</ISA02>

      <ISA16/>
      <GS>
         <GS06>1</GS06>
         <GS07>X</GS07>
         <GS08>005010X221A1</GS08>
         <ST>
            <ST01>835</ST01>
            <ST02>0001</ST02>
            <BPR/>
            <TRN/>
            <DTM/>
            <Loop1000A/>
            <Loop1000B/>
            <Loop2000/>
            <PLB/>
         </ST>
          <ST>
              <ST01>835</ST01>
              <ST02>0001</ST02>
              <BPR/>
              <TRN/>
              <DTM/>
              <Loop1000A/>
              <Loop1000B/>
              <Loop2000/>
              <PLB/>
          </ST>
      </GS>
   </ISA>
</edi835>
```

My basic problem is that, I have a field in a parent element that tells me what the subtype is up the child field

> <GS08>005010X223A2</GS08>

What's the correct way to do this?

I Basically Want a XmlTypeAdapter that can take me from 1 bound-type to another. Like: "Give me the first elements and I will tell you what to do with the rest of them"
An object factory might be able to do this. Hope this is clear

Each <ST> structure can be so radically different that really, what I want to do is just specify up until that <ST> and then let it reflect the rest of the types from there.

I have completely replaced the original, contrived XML with ACTUAL XML (condensed). I solved it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26952965/polymorphic-xml-binding-with-jaxb/) but it's ugly

Answer (score 1):

## Don't Do It

> My basic problem is that, I have a field in a parent element that
>   tells me what the subtype is up the child field (qualifier). What's
>   the correct way to do this?

I wouldn't do it this way since it doesn't correspond to a standard way of representing inheritance in XML.  This means that you will have to jump through hoops to process it, as will everyone else that needs to interact with this XML.

---

## What to Do Instead

Drop the `qualifier` element and keep everything else the same.  This makes the subtypes the element name the qualifier.  This corresponds to the XML Schema concept of substitution groups, and is a standard way of representing inheritance.  It also makes your XML a bit shorter which is a good thing.

### Java Model

**Inner**

You will use the `@XmlElementRef` annotation on the `problemType` field/property on the `Inner` class.  The type to be unmarshalled will be based element encountered, and which subtype has a matching `@XmlRootElement` annotation.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Inner {

    @XmlElementRef
    private ProblemType problemType;

}
```

**ProblemType1**

```
@XmlRootElement(name="ProblemType1")
public class ProblemType1 extends ProblemType {
}
```

**ProblemType2**

```
@XmlRootElement(name="ProblemType2")
public class ProblemType2 extends ProblemType {
}
```

Comment: I have since changed the details of the question for Clarity. I have no choice but to use the qualifier. It isn't my XML. I was hoping You would answer this question. This is a clarifying question to one I posted here where I answered it ugly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26952965/polymorphic-xml-binding-with-jaxb/

Comment: I was reading your piece on substitution groups and (earlier) about moxy predicates. I think a MOXY predicate would work